# Speed up HTML scraping in R

Tags: r, readlines, doparallel, ncbi

I am currently using `readlines()` to pull the HTML code into a temporary object in R but finding this slow. What tool would people recommend is faster for a performing a large number of iterations?

For background I am looking at some ancestary DNA results which have 600,000+ potential vatiants to look at.

Current code:

```
   for (rs in seq(1,nrow(ancest_DNA)))
      temp_rs <- ancest_DNA[rs,"rsid"]
      print(paste0("Iteration ",which(ancest_DNA$rsid == temp_rs)))
      print(paste0("RSID ",temp_rs))
      #Search for any clinical significance on Clinvar
      NCBI <- readLines(paste("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/",temp_rs,sep = ""),n = 800)
```

**Updated code using reutils**

```
for(rs in seq(1, nrow(ancest_DNA))) {
  temp_rs <- ancest_DNA[rs,"rsid"]
  info <- efetch(temp_rs, db = "snp", strand = 1)
  info2 <- xmlToDataFrame(info$`.->content`)
  print(paste0("Interation: ", rs))
  ancest_DNA[rs,"ClinSig"] <- info2["1","CLINICAL_SIGNIFICANCE"]
  ancest_DNA[rs,"Gene"] <- info2["1","GENES"]
  temp_allele <- info2$SPDI
  temp_allele2 <- strsplit(temp_allele, ",")
  for (nt in seq(1,length(temp_allele2[[1]]))) {
    temp_allele2[[1]][nt] <- str_extract(temp_allele2[[1]][nt], "(?<=:\\D:).*")
  }
  if (length(temp_allele2[[1]]) == 1) {
    ancest_DNA[rs,"PathAllele"] <- temp_allele2[[1]]
  }
  if (length(temp_allele2[[1]]) == 2) {
    ancest_DNA[rs,"PathAllele"] <- temp_allele2[[1]][1]
    ancest_DNA[rs,"PathAllele2"] <- temp_allele2[[1]][2]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running your requests in parallell, rather than in a `for`-loop? This way you would be able to make several requests simoultaneously. However, you should always check the terms of service of the page you are scraping.

Additionally, you would be better off using their API.
For NCBI, take a look at their [E-utility tool](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25497/#chapter2.Usage_Guidelines_and_Requiremen)

Comment: Thanks mhovd I had tried to get the E-utility tool to work but struggled with it before, I have now got efetch to work which has significantly reduced the time for each iteration

I cannot get the **doparellel** package to work I will post the updated code below, any ideas?